# Flask: View function did not return a response for js file

Tags: python, flask

i build a website with python-flask.In a page i loaded a javascript file.Here's my file structure:

```
/python
   /static
     /plugins
     /themes
       /default
          /js
            /my-js.js
   /templates
     /my-file.html
   /venv
   app.py
```

I have included my-js.js in my-file.html.

There is also other scripts are succesfully loaded the page(which are in the same dir with my-js.js) before this js.

When i call my file with the url `/static/themes/default/js/my-js.js`
it says `ValueError: View function did not return a response` with the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ozcan/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1701, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/Users/ozcan/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1689, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "/Users/ozcan/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1687, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/ozcan/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1361, in full_dispatch_request
    response = self.make_response(rv)
  File "/Users/ozcan/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1439, in make_response
    raise ValueError('View function did not return a response')
ValueError: View function did not return a response
```

Why is it happennig? I did not wrote a route for static files such as these js.How come other js files are being loaded and this one is not?

Answer (score 1):

A few things I can think of offhand. First, it looks like you're trying to pass an absolute path to my-js.js, when really you want a relative path, try the URL "static/themes/default/js/my-js.js" (no leading slash) and see if that helps.

Also, without seeing your python or Javascript, it's hard to confirm this, but are you setting the appropriate mimetype in your response object (it should be application/javascript)?